# count consecutive number of -1 in a column. count >=14

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out query to count "-1" that have occurred for more than 14 times. Can anyone help me here. I tried everything from lead, row number, etc but nothing is working out.
[image: select output]

The BP is recorded for every minute and I need to figure the id's who's bp_level was "-1" for more than 14min

Comment: MySQl <> MS SQL Server. Please tag correctly your RDBMS

Comment: Looks like a MS SQL Server screenshot... TAG RESPONSIBLY.     Seems you are looking for a Gaps-and-Islands solution.

Comment: Also best to post sample data and desired results in formatted TEXT.

Comment: Are the readings always exactly 1 minute apart? Or can there be some fluctuation in the timings?

Comment: When you have tried something it helps to show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        count(case when bp_level = 1 then 1 end) over
            (partition by person_id order by time) as grp
    from T
)
select distinct person_id
from data
where bp_level = -1
group by person_id, grp
having count(*) > 14; /* = or >= ? */
```

If you want to rely on timestamps rather than a count of rows then you could  use the time difference:

```
...
-- where 1 = 1 /* all rows */
group by person_id, grp
having datediff(minute, min(time), max(time)) > 14;
```

The accepted answer would have issues with scenarios where there are multiple rows with the same timestamp if there's any potential for that to happen.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ad6a1b515bb4091efba9b8831e5d579

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following:

```
Select Distinct B.Person_ID, B.[Consecutive]
From
(
  Select D.person_ID, COUNT(D.bp_level) Over (Partition By D.grp, D.person_ID Order By D.Time_) [Consecutive]
  From
  (
    Select Time_, Person_ID, bp_level,
           DATEADD(Minute, -ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By Person_ID Order By Time_), Time_) grp
    From mytable Where bp_level = -1
  ) D
) B
Where B.[Consecutive] >= 14
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f14dc2f86909fd6eeef35fc757946396). Using SQL Server.

`DATEADD(Minute, -ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By Person_ID Order By Time_), Time_)`: to define a unique group for consecutive times per person, where (bp_level = -1).

`COUNT(D.bp_level) Over (Partition By D.grp, D.person_ID Order By D.Time_)`: to find the cumulative sum of bp_level over the increasing of time for each group.

Once a none -1 value appeared the group will split into two groups and the counter will reset to 0 for the other group.

**NOTE:** this solution works only if there are no gaps between the consecutive times, the time is increased by one minute for each row/ person, otherwise, the query will not work but can be modified to cover the gaps.